# Groovy script to split a file line at ',' and create a new XML file

Tags: groovy

I am very new to Groovy and trying to figure my way out.

I am trying to write a groovy to split the lines of a file on encountering ',' and then write a if condition based on the first two characters of the line. After that I wanted to create a XML file using the different data in the file. This is how far I have reached.

```
def Message processData(Message message) {
    //Body 
       def body = message.getBody(java.lang.String)as String;
       
       def varStringWriter = new StringWriter();
       def varXMLBuilder   = new MarkupBuilder(varStringWriter);
       
       String newItem ;
       body.eachLine{
            line -> newItem = line ;
            String newItem1 = newItem.substring(0,2).trim();
            String newItem2 = newItem.substring(3,11).trim();
            varXMLBuilder.RECORD{
                node1(newItem1);
                node2(newItem2);
            }
        }
        def xml = varStringWriter.toString();
        xml="<RECORDS>"+xml+"</RECORDS>" ;

        message.setBody(xml);
        
       return message;
}
```

In the above code I tried to use offset but, since each of my file lines are of different length it wont work.
Please help me handle this issue.

Regards,
Nisha

Comment: `.substring(x)` will give you "from x to end"

Answer (score 0):

Splitting on a character can be done like this:

```
data = 'axaratgxrgc,rxregxsergcs'

def lines = data.split(/,/)

assert lines[0] == 'axaratgxrgc'
assert lines[1] == 'rxregxsergcs'
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, first of all, to groovy and Stack Overflow :)

You can use `tokenize()` to split a string, as shown bellow.
And yeah, don't worry about `;` in groovy ;)

```
def Message processData(Message message) {
   //Body 
   def body = message.getBody(java.lang.String) as String;
   
   def varStringWriter = new StringWriter()
   def varXMLBuilder   = new MarkupBuilder(varStringWriter)

   body.eachLine { line -> 
        def newItems = line.tokenize(',') // input is a list of chars that will split your string, usually better than .split()
        String newItem1 = newItems.first() // looks like you want just two items
        String newItem2 = newItems.last()  // but you can use as an array as well newItems[0] and newItems[1]
        varXMLBuilder.RECORD {
            node1(newItem1)
            node2(newItem2)
        }
    }

    def xml = varStringWriter.toString()
    xml="<RECORDS>${xml}</RECORDS>" // you can use ${} to add a variable inside a string

    message.setBody(xml)
    
    return message
}
```